# Ubuntu 14.10 freeze after login

Tags: login, freeze, 14.10

I just upgraded an  Intel® Core™ i5-2500K Desktop from 14.04 to 14.10 
System is multi-user/multi-language.
following the upgrade, I managed to log-in with the only Sudoer user, had a "restart Nautilus" prompt, which worked. 
However, all other users are stuck following log-in.
Mouse works, but nothing else.

Going to tty mode (Ctrl+Alt+F1), and starting nautilus from xterm:
xterm -display:0 -e nautilus 
results with error:

```
(nautilis:3761): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.free.desktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: the name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
```

and

```
(naultius:3761): CRITICAL: **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion 'NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
```

any help?

Comment: any suggestions (aside of "clean install") will greatly help - even what to check

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569119/laptop-freezes-whenever-i-unplug-plug-in-ac-adapter?noredirect=1#comment787688_569119) could be your lead, we're trying to resolve this issue here.